# Why undefined proper $identifier is showing on error log but not in UI

Tags: php, wordpress

```
class MPF_Miinto_Main
{
    private $sandbox;

    private $identifier;

    private $secret;

    public function __construct($config)
    {
        $this->sandbox = $config->sandbox;
        $this->identifier = $config->identifier;
        $this->secret = $config->secret;
    }
```

}

It shows:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$sandbox in
>   /var/www/html/exportfeed/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-miinto/core/classes/miinto-main.php
>   on line 28 PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$identifier in
>   /var/www/html/exportfeed/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-miinto/core/classes/miinto-main.php
>   on line 31 PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$secret in
>   /var/www/html/exportfeed/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-miinto/core/classes/miinto-main.php
>   on line 32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have [`display_errors`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) set to `0`.